# How to make a Makefile shorter?

Tags: makefile

I've got the following Makefile:

```
all: hello.exe hellogtk.exe hellogtktng.cs

hello.exe: hello.cs
 gmcs hello.cs

hellogtk.exe: hellogtk.cs
 gmcs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 hellogtk.cs

hellogtktng.exe: hellogtktng.cs
 gmcs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 hellogtktng.cs

clean:
 rm -f *.exe
```

I'm only starting to learn how to write Makefiles, and I feel that all this is a bit repetitive. How would Makefile pros go about doing this?

Answer (score 7):

```
all: hello.exe hellogtk.exe hellogtktng.exe

%.exe: %.cs
 gmcs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 $<

clean:
 rm -f *.exe
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, it works! Would you mind pointing me to documentation about this? It looks intimidatingly perl-y.

Do I understand it correctly that I would compile hello.cs with gtk-sharp-2.0 (which doesn't require it) then? Can I do something like this? (it doesn't work like that)

hello.exe: %.cs
  gmcs $<

Comment: @theone, more specifically, [Defining and Redefining Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) section

Answer (score 6):

[Here's how you can add flags to specific targets.](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/make/Target_002dspecific.html)

```
# An empty variable for flags (Not strictly neccessary, 
# undefined variables expand to an empty string)
GMCSFLAGS =

# The first target is made if you don't specify arguments
all: hello.exe hellogtk.exe hellogtktng.exe

# Add flags to specific files
hellogtk.exe hellogtktng.exe: GCMSFLAGS = -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0

# A pattern rule to transform .cs to .exe
# The percent sign is substituted when looking for dependancies
%.exe:%.cs
    gmcs $(GMCSFLAGS) $<
# $() expands a variable, $< is the first dependancy in the list
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! It does exactly the same as my original Makefile!